# TypeORM Entity Metadata not found

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

ho,

I'm trying to build a backend for a type of e-commerce site using NestJS + TypeORM.

I need a m:n relation between my order and the products table. However, since I need some custom fields within the pivot table I looked up typeorms documentation and as stated there I need to create a new entity which I've done. Now I get an error starting up my NestJS application:

```
Error: Entity metadata for Product#productToOrders was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
```

`product.entity.ts`:

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { ProductToOrder } from "./productToOrder.entity";

@Entity()
export class Product extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    
    @Column()
    name: string;
    
    @Column()
    description: string;
    
    @Column()
    price: number;

    @OneToMany(type => ProductToOrder, productToOrder => productToOrder.product)
    productToOrders: ProductToOrder[];
}
```

`productToOrder.entity.ts`:

```
import { Order } from "src/order/order.entity";
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Product } from "./product.entity";

@Entity()
export class ProductToOrder extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    amount: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Product, product => product.productToOrders,{eager: false})
    product: Product;

    @ManyToOne(() => Order, order => order.productToOrders, {eager: false})
    order: Order;
}
```

`order.entity.ts`:

```
import { User } from "src/auth/user.entity";
import { Product } from "src/product/product.entity";
import { ProductToOrder } from "src/product/productToOrder.entity";
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, JoinTable, ManyToMany, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Order extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    ordernumber: number;

    @Column()
    totalprice: number;
    
    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.orders, {eager: false})
    user_id: User[];

    @OneToMany(() => ProductToOrder, productToOrder => productToOrder.order, {eager: true})
    productToOrders: ProductToOrder[];
}
```

My directory structure:

```
src/
├── order
│   ├── order.entity.ts
│   ├── order.module.ts
│   ├── order.service.ts
│   ├── order.controller.ts
│   └── order.repository.ts
├── product
│   ├── product.entity.ts
│   ├── product.module.ts
│   ├── product.service.ts
│   ├── product.controller.ts
│   ├── productToOrder.entity.ts <- I put the entity for the pivot table here, not sure if its right
│   └── product.repository.ts
└── xy
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { typeOrmConfig } from './config/typeorm.config';
import { ProductModule } from './product/product.module';
import { OrderModule } from './order/order.module';


@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
    AuthModule,
    ProductModule,
    OrderModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`typeorm.config.ts`:

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import * as config from 'config';

const dbConfig = config.get('db');

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: dbConfig.type,
    host: dbConfig.host,
    port: dbConfig.port,
    username: dbConfig.username,
    password: dbConfig.password,
    database: dbConfig.database,
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: dbConfig.synchronize,
}
```

If I add the

```
entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
```

line to my `typeorm.config.ts` and start the application with `npm run start:dev` the error changes to:

```
 TypeError: metatype is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 11):

I received the same error and it took me hours to debug. In the end, I had forgotten `@Entity()` on at least one of my Entity classes.

Comment: I highly highly recommend anyone using TypeORM to use Prisma instead. We are moving significantly faster now and no longer hemorrhaging money to SQL contractors. TypeORM is a box of lies.

Answer (score 5):

In your TypeORM config, you must have defined the `entities` attribute:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  // ...
  entities: ['src/**/*.entity.ts']
})
```

Check that the pattern also matches your new entity.

Comment: i did that, it matches my pattern aswell, now i get an error saying it cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: This is a TypeScript issue, it is possible that you have to use.a pattern with the `dist/` directory since your files are built.

Comment: tried it, i changed up my question a bit and added a bit more code to make i more clearly

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what would be the solution for you. I had the same kind of problems in my project, and I ended up using an array of classes rather than a string pattern to handle better the "source vs. dist" dilemma. So rather than `entities: ['src/**/*.entity.ts']` I used: `entities: [Product, Order, ProductOrder]`. It allowed me to be sure I avoided bugs like this. The obvious drawback is that you have to add by yourself a new entity each time you create one.

Comment: Weird, why is `autoLoadEntities: true,` not working?

Answer (score 3):

### It's a very simple issue...

However, its error comes from the `source-data.ts` file, for your time it comes from the `typeOrmConfig`.

> So, let's see how we can fix this issue....

**Just include all of the entities inside your** `entities: [Product, Order, Etc]` array.

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "DB_NAME",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3306,
  username: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "DB_NAME",
  synchronize: true, // synchronize should be true...
  logging: false,
  entities: [Order, Product], // define our all of entity
});
```

Answer (score 1):

okey so the problem wasnt my typeorm config, neither my entities.

The problem was my PassportJS middleware. within my order.controller.ts

looked like this:

```js
import { Body, Controller, Post, UseGuards, UsePipes, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { GetUser } from 'src/auth/get-user.decorator';
import { User } from 'src/auth/user.entity';
import { CreateOrderDto } from './dto/create-order.dto';
import { OrderService } from './order.service';

@Controller('order')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
export class OrderController {
    constructor(
        private orderService: OrderService,
    ){}

    @Post()
    @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
    createProduct(
        @Body(ValidationPipe) createdto: CreateOrderDto,
        @GetUser() user: User,
    ){
        return this.orderService.createOrder(createdto, user);
    }
}
```

as you can see im missing brackets within the

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
```

decorator. What it really shouldve looked like:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard()) //<-- Missing brackets
```

i found inspiration for this solution right here:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2399

Answer (score 0):

maybe you not add the ProductToOrder entity to productModule?

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Product, ProductToOrder])],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use webpack when build your app? if you do I have the same issue so.. for fix it in a dev mode i put the nest-cli.ts archive like that.

```
   {
      "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
      "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "webpack": false
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error and it was because I had an attribute of type "Event" meant to point at an Event entity, but it was using a generic Javascript object (had to import my entity model), check your types and imports on recently added entities.